# Whitelabel Error Page Thingsboard-2.0

Tags: java, maven, thingsboard

I have clone the thingsboard repository from github version 2.0 and compile the source code. When I installed the deb package I am getting Whitelabel Error.

My configuration is:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Node: v10.1.0
Npm: 6.0.1
```

I have changed ui/pom.xml file as below

```
<nodeVersion>v8.9.4</nodeVersion>
<npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
```

Command used:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1G"
mvn -X clean install -DskipTests
```

Build successfully completed.
When I try to access using localhost:8080. I got below error.

```
Whitelabel Error Page 
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, 
so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Jun 05 09:36:28 IST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). 
No message available
```

Log Message:

```
ERROR org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'error.vm' in any resource loader.
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the proper steps to build the thingsboard?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps.
1) go to UI module using: cd ${TB_WORK_DIR}/ui
2) start npm: mvn clean install -P npm-start
3) after starting npm hit 'localhost:3000' in browser

if above solution not solved isssue try below also:
Check the package.json file in UI. there may be some packages versions changed. replace updated versions with the old version.